# How do I execute code AFTER a form has loaded (Compact Framework 3.5)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

We want execute code after the form has loaded on a Win CE 5.0 powered device. The application is being developed using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (C#).

I have tried to approach [the `Shown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) which unfortunately doesn't include in the Compact Framework (as far as I am aware). Is there a similar function?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the exact same way the Shown event is fired in the desktop version:

```
    private void Shown() {
        this.Update();
        // etc...
    }

    private delegate void MethodInvoker();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Shown));
    }
```

Not actually sure if calling Update() is necessary on CF.  It does no harm.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker` doesn't seem to be available.